# What stops the tab?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, tabstop

I have the following xaml:

```
       <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemProperties.GeneralProperties}" Grid.Row="1"
                 Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="320" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PropertyInput}}" Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

where the ContentPresenter contains a TextBox, or a ComboBox, or a CheckBox.

To switch between the controls I need twice press the tab. Why???

I've already tried to comment the whole first column, without the TextBlock, unsuccessfully.

Comment: Do you have a ListBoxItemStyle applied to your ListBox? also you need to check the styles of your input controls.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for a DataGrid (which has a similar templating system).

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>                                          
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then anything which is a TabStop within the datagrid would work as a tabstop, but nothing else. Sorry I'm not sure what the equivalent code is for ListBox - but you may be able to figure it out from this.